# Sending transaction success verification in resellerclub

Tags: php, transactions, confirmation

Resellerclub custom payment gateway integration :
http://manage.uk.resellerclub.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq411.html
I need to send transaction success message to resellerclub in order to assign the purchased product to the client. delivery.php gives transaction status.

My postpayment.php

```
<?php
session_start();
///session_save_path("./");
require("functions.php");
require ("delivery.php");   
?>



<html>
<head><title>Post Payment</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<font size=4>
<?php
$key = "AfKdTauRYnPQUFztasCNkr9yCLCfeQhd";


$transId = $_REQUEST['pid'];
$rid = $_REQUEST['rid'];

# Display/execute steps according to status.
echo "Transaction ID: " . $pid . "<br>";
echo "Gateway ID: " . $rid . "<br>";
echo "Transaction Status: " . $_SESSION['TRANSACTION_STATUS'] . "<br>";
echo "Redirect URL: ". $_SESSION['redirecturl'] . "<br><br>";

# Check transaction status value
if($_SESSION['TRANSACTION_STATUS'] == "SUCCESS")
$status = "Y";
else
$status = "N";


srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$rkey = rand();

$redirectUrl = $_SESSION['redirecturl']; 
$sellingCurrencyAmount = $_SESSION['sellingcurrencyamount'];
$accountingCurrencyAmount = $_SESSION['accountingcurencyamount'];   

 $checksum      =generateChecksum($transId,$sellingCurrencyAmount,$accountingCurrencyAmount,$status, $rkey,$key);   

echo "<a href=" . $redirectUrl . "?" . "transid=" . $transId . "&status=" .      $status . "&rkey=" . $rkey . "&checksum=" . $checksum . "&sellingamount=" . $sellingCurrencyAmount . "&accountingamount=" . $accountingCurrencyAmount . ">"  . "</a>";

$rURL = $redirectUrl . "?" . "transid=" . $transId . "&status=" . $status .  "&rkey=" . $rkey . "&checksum=" . $checksum . "&sellingamount=" . $sellingCurrencyAmount . "&accountingamount=" . $accountingCurrencyAmount;

echo "<br><br>";
?>
Redirecting....
<form name="f1" method="post" action="<?php echo $redirectUrl;?>">   
<input type="hidden" name="transid" value="<?php echo $transId;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="<?php echo $status;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rkey" value="<?php echo $rkey;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="checksum" value="<?php echo $checksum;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sellingamount" value="<?php echo  $sellingCurrencyAmount;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="accountingamount" value="<?php echo     $accountingCurrencyAmount;?>">

<input type="submit" value="Click here to Continue"><BR>
</form>



<script>
window.location = "<?php echo $rURL; ?>";
</script>
```

Still the payments show authstarted and i need to manually approve the payments. Any solution ??

the page postpayment.php is not directly visible during checkout. I tried to add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

    function submitform(){
      alert('test');
      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    }

    function autoRefresh(){
       clearTimeout(auto);
       auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 10000);
     }
   }
   </script>
```

This is to auto submit the form on page load. Still not working..

Comment: If I'm getting you right, you are getting payment response from Resellerclub which is that payment is authstarted (assuming that payment is approved and completed) but you want to approve the payment at your end ?

Comment: It shows authstarted but i want it to be auto approved